# Card Flip IE animation issue

Tags: html, css

I've created a flip animation but on IE browser specifically IE10, IE11 it seems that the text is reversing when the card is flipped.

I've added all the browser prefixes as the example below but still having issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/uxable/YHeKX/

```
<div class="flip"> 
  <div class="card"> 
    <div class="face front">Front</div> 
    <div class="face back">Back</div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS Below

```
body {
 background: #ccc;   
}
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
  -ms-perspective: 800;
  -moz-perspective: 800;
  -o-perspective: 800;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  transform:rotatey(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Opera */
}
.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  font-family: Georgia;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;  /* W3C */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari & Chrome */
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Firefox */
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Opera */

}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;

  transform:rotatey(-180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
  -moz-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -o-transform:rotatey(-180deg); /* Opera */

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating flip card with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830170/creating-flip-card-with-css) and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933711/css-card-flip-internet-explorer and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742507/css-flip-card-internet-explorer-issue

Answer (score 1):

IE 10/11 doesn't support the `transform-style: preserve-3d` property.

Src: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/csstransformspreserve3d

Possible workarounds:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh673529(v=vs.85).aspx
- [Creating flip card with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26830170/creating-flip-card-with-css)
- [css card flip internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933711/css-card-flip-internet-explorer)
- [CSS Flip card Internet Explorer issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742507/css-flip-card-internet-explorer-issue)

Comment: @Phreak Updated my answer with a link